# window.innerheight can not exclude addressbar in emulator

Tags: javascript

I am going to get the actual viewport height that exclude addressbar in emulator
And window.innerWidth can not exclude addressbar height in emulator testing
pls help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.outerHeight`  for calculate device height ;

Comment: window.outerHeight is calculated deviceHeight
I am going to get heigtht exclude addressbar in emulator